# iPhone - getting an array instead of an array of dictionaries from Core Data

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have something like this on my core data class to fetch all data of kind "dataX" from the database, as an array...

```
+ (NSArray *)allDataInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    NSArray *allData = nil;

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"myData" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    [request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"dataX"]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    allData = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    [request release];

    return allData;
}
```

The problem is that this returns an array of dictionaries and in this case, each dictionary contains just one pair object/key.

As all the keys on all dictionaries on that array are equal to "dataX", I would like to receive, instead, an array containing just the values... so instead of this

```
array { dictionary1, dictionary2...
dictionary1 = one object for key "dataX" (lets call it object1)
dictionary2 = one object for key "dataX" (lets call it object2)
etc...
```

I would like to receive this

```
array {object1, object2, ...
```

is there a way to do that in the fetch itself?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)allDataInManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    NSMutableArray *allData = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSMutableArray *returnableArray=[NSMutableArray array];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"myData" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    [request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"dataX"]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    allData = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    [request release];

   for(int i=0;i<[allData count];i++)
   {
     [returnableArray addObject:[[allData objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"dataX"]];
   }
    return returnableArray;
}
```

use this.

Comment: I was thinking of some kind of way of doing it in the fetch itself, but, anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I particularly appreciated this question for its explanation that a fetch with an NSDictionaryResultType `returns an array of dictionaries`, one dictionary per target object. (That may be obvious in retrospect, but it’s not spelled out anywhere in the Apple docs.)

In case anybody else is looking at this, there is a way of doing almost exactly what Digital Robot requests:

Simply replace `return allData;` with `return [allData valueForKey:@"dataX"];`

This makes use of the nifty NSArray method `valueForKey:`, which digs into the array’s dictionary elements and returns an array of values for the specified key from each dictionary.

The only downside is that all those dictionary pointers returned by the fetch are taking up memory. This problem could be eliminated by enclosing the call to `allDataInManagedObjectContext:` in a nested autorelease pool, like this:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *subpool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 
NSArray *arrayOfValuesDesired = [NameOfClassDefiningStaticMethod allDataInManagedObjectContext:theContext];
// Loop through the array, calling “retain” on each of its elements, and then add a routine to this class’s dealloc method that releases each element.
self.aPropertyThatRetainsItsValues = arrayOfValuesDesired;
[subpool drain];
```